# Запись аудио-файла с микрофона в формате LPCM без WAV-заголовка на C#

Tags: c#

Стоит задача записи аудио файла в формате LPCM (без WAV-заголовка). Подскажите, какой библиотекой можно воспользоваться для формирования аудио-файла требуемого формата?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать воспользоваться [Bass.NET](http://bass.radio42.com/) просто заголовок не добавлять.
Пример работы с Bass.NET можно посмотреть этой [статье](http://streletzcoder.ru/bass-net-zapisyivaem-zvuk-pravilno/).